# Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line contains embedded null (using livereload, node-inspector, and karma)

Tags: node.js, websocket, karma-runner, livereload, node-inspector

Whenever I use something in my Terminal that requires a websocket to Chrome or Safari (livereload, node-inspector, karma), I get the following console error "Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line contains embedded null"  Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This happens on safari as well.